# disable colorbox on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mobile, responsive-design, colorbox

I'm using colorbox on my responsive web project, i tweaked it a bit for my needs and it looks great, but when i open it on mobile devices it appears smaller than the thumbnails, so i need to disable colorbox on small screen sizes. I've tried some solutions from other web sites but i cant make it work. Can someone help?

This is my original script:

```
    <script src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){   

        //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
        $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
        $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2'});
        $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3'});

        $.colorbox.settings.maxWidth  = '98%';
        $.colorbox.settings.maxHeight = '98%';
        $.colorbox.settings.speed = 200;

        $(window).resize(function(){
        // Resize Colorbox when resizing window or changing mobile device orientation
        resizeColorBox();
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", resizeColorBox, false);
        });

        var resizeTimer;
        function resizeColorBox() {
        if (resizeTimer) {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        }
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        if (jQuery('#cboxOverlay').is(':visible')) {
        jQuery.colorbox.reload();
        }}, 300);}  
    });
</script>
```

This is the html (where i'm testing the colorbox):

```
    <div id="test" class="one-third column">
               <a class="group1" href="images/portfolio/aproval-tree.png" title="test">
               <img class="fade" src="images/portfolio/aproval-tree.png" style="background-image:url(images/portfolio/zoom_full.png);"></a>
               <a class="group1" href="images/portfolio/dyrup/dyrup_ad.png" title="test"><img style="display:none"></a>
               <a class="group1" href="images/portfolio/dyrup/dyrup_outdoor.png" title="test"><img style="display:none"></a>
        </div>
```

This is one of the solutions i tried:

```
    <script src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        if (window.matchMedia) {

        // Establishing media check (web solution)
        width481Check = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 481px)");
        if (width481Check.matches){
            $.colorbox.remove();
        }}  

        //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
        $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
        $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2'});
        $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3'});

        $.colorbox.settings.maxWidth  = '98%';
        $.colorbox.settings.maxHeight = '98%';
        $.colorbox.settings.speed = 200;

        $(window).resize(function(){
        // Resize Colorbox when resizing window or changing mobile device orientation
        resizeColorBox();
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", resizeColorBox, false);
        });

        var resizeTimer;
        function resizeColorBox() {
        if (resizeTimer) {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        }
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        if (jQuery('#cboxOverlay').is(':visible')) {
        jQuery.colorbox.reload();
        }}, 300);}  
    });
</script>
```

This one uses matchMedia, but i cant make it work. Any solutions?

Comment: You can set colorbox if window's sizes fits your needs, can't you?

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i just got it to work, seems i was putting the new code on a wrong order of the script. It's not very elegant but it does the trick when i resize the browser window. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/3FkcV/  I still need to test this on an acutal mobile device. But there is a new small issue that it might be fixed with your help, after reducing the browser window and disabling colorbox, it stays disabled even when i maximize the browser window again. Is there a way to reverse this, making it available when i pass a min width?

Comment: i think you are giving wrong `rel` value when reenabling colorbox? I tried it way you do it. It is working with correct `rel` value.

Comment: could you show me where i did wrong in jsfiddle plz?

Comment: in line 7,8,9 you are activating colorbox with `group1` css class for selector but when you reenabling it in line 50, you are using `colorbox` css class for selector. Sorry for my late answer.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your replies. I tried changing from colorbox to group1 but it doesn't work. It's okay because the essential function is working, when it's opened in small screens it deactivates. Thanks again for your help.